# Unable to Readspecific characteristic from BLE Device with python

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I scan all available characteristics with python i get:

```
INFO:__main__:[Service] 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 1): Generic Attribute 
Profile
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 2):  
(indicate), Value: None
INFO:__main__:      [Descriptor] 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 4): Client 
Characteristic Configuration) | Value: b'\x02\x00'
INFO:__main__:[Service] 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 5): Generic Access 
Profile
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 6):   
(read,write-without-response,write,authenticated-signed-writes), Value: b'HRSTM'
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 8):  
(read,write-without-response,write,authenticated-signed-writes), Value: b'@\x03'
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 10):  (read), 
Value: b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff'
```

Problem is that I can't read characteristic that has (indicate) permision. I can read any characteristic from above that has read permission.
Why Can't I read those with indicate permision?

When I use my phone and connect to BLE, I can see value of any characteristic, even those that I can't read via pc. (for example characteristic as Handle: 1.

Here is my Python code:

```
import sys
import platform
import asyncio
import logging

from bleak import BleakClient
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
UUID = "00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
ADDRESS = (
"00:80:E1:26:C4:5E"
if platform.system() != "Darwin"
else "B9EA5233-37EF-4DD6-87A8-2A875E821C46"
)
async def main(address):
async with BleakClient(address) as client:
    while True :
        value =  bytes(await client.read_gatt_char(UUID));
        await asyncio.sleep(1, 0);
        print(value)
if __name__ == "__main__":
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ADDRESS))
```

Here is error I get when I run the code above:

```
bleak.exc.BleakError: Could not read characteristic handle 2: Protocol Error 0x02: Read Not 
Permitted
```

Comment: You want to read the characteristic `00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`? This is the Service Changed characteristic. Your log states that it ONLY has the indicate permission, no reading or writing allowed. Why do you want to read it?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I resolved problem by enabling notify event, that's why I was getting error because there were no permission from client side

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried to hint you on. Glad you figured it out! maybe you want to answer your own question and provide your fixed code for others to find?

Comment: Sure, will do that now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

I found out that I need to crate some notify handler that will give me permision to read date from choosen characteristic

Here is code that does it:

```
def notification_handler(sender, data):
    """Simple notification handler which prints the data received."""
    output_numbers = list(data)
    print(output_numbers)

async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        await client.start_notify(UUID, notification_handler)
        await asyncio.sleep(10.0)
        await client.stop_notify(UUID)
```